# Responsive table (table-responsive) not scrolling in mobile. [bootstrap 3]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a lot of problems lately with bootstrap :/

Its because I'm new to it and kinda learning how to master it.
I am currently having a problem which in browsers in full-zoom mode (250% zoom) it will make the table responsive and add a scroll to the table and in the mobile,
it will just not add the Scroll, so I cant scroll.

Code is as follows :

```html
                                    <div>
                                <div style="margin-top: 10px">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Section 1</th>
                                                <th>Section 2</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="col-xs-4">
                                                  <div>Some Text</div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="col-xs-8">
                                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>#1</td>
                                                            <td style="text-align: center"><span style="font-size: 14px">TEST</span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Images - [image]

I hope you guys can help me fix the problem, I have been trying to fix it for the past 2hours, no success. Thank you all :)
**EDIT: JSFiddle with CSS included -> http://jsfiddle.net/gausxmww/**

Comment: Please make your example into [a runnable code snippet.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Footable for responsive grid.

Check this:
http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/?url=http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/metro-theme.htm

Comment: I have already checked this option before and installed it. but it did not work for me for some reason.

Comment: you are working on which platform e.g. Asp.net or plain HTML ??

Comment: I have created small example, check this: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/q5pzyx7t/)
data-hide is the important attribute for responsive table so you just need to use "phone", "tablet" value for hiding the colomns according to screen resolution.